# Customers cannot install Package if Quotes is disabled (Which is default behavior )Installation complains "Missing Organization Feature: Quotes"

Tags: custom-button, visualforce-component, package, quote

1) Adding functionality for e-signature "Sign Document" button in App setup -->Customize -->
Quotes --> Buttons and Links --> Custom Buttons and Links --> New Button for
 "Sign Document" and created a package but The button  "Sign Document" did not show up on the Quote page layout.

2) To resolve, added components to the package (Add component --> button or link -->  Sign Document --> Add to package --> then upload package ) On making package it by default check that Quotes is a dependency and does not allow to uncheck. when users tried to install that package it throws the error package install Error: Missing Organization features :Quotes"

3) Step 1 does not give them  "Sign Document" custom button and Step 2 does not allow them to install package without activating Quotes for their organization. We have a lot customers and we cant force them to activate Quotes while installation.

Is there a Solution to include custom button  "Sign Document" visible on Quotes layout without forcing them to activate quotes while installation? Is there a work around.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider an extension package. The base package would not include the quote features, while the extension package would. This means there would be two installs instead of one, but it would satisfy the requirements.